# Traveling through Istanbul on two different airlines do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, us-citizens, turkey, istanbul

I'm having difficulty figuring out my visa situation going through Istanbul.

1. I'm a US citizen.
2. I'll be traveling from Mumbai, and connecting through Manama, on Gulf Air before changing airlines to Turkish Airlines in Istanbul and flying to Vienna which is my final destination.

Do I need a visa with the diplomatic spat between the US and Turkey? And do I need to pick up my luggage and go through customs again to get onto my Turkish airlines flight?

Comment: Is it on one ticket? Or was it independently booked?

Comment: The 'diplomatic spat' is irrelevant as it ended long ago.  The real question, as as has already been asked, if whether this is one ticket or two.

Comment: Check https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293974-i368-k6892063-Do_i_Need_a_Turkey_transit_VISA_at_Istanbul_airport-Istanbul.html

Comment: Also is your arrival and departure airport in Istanbul the same? There are two airports in Istanbul.